# How i can filter only true value from object and maintain the object structure

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my current object which i get but i want to filter out only true values and also maintain the same structure in return.

Current Object =

```
errors :{
    frontdesk: {
      PreAudit: true,
      AuthSent: false,
      Limitation: false,
    },

    clinical: {
      medicaid: true,
      Vitals: true,
      Height: false,
    },
    eligibilityVerification: {
      Mentioned: true,
      EVAttached: false,
    }
  }
```

```
i want like this =
```

errors :{
frontdesk: {
PreAudit: true,
},

```
clinical: {
  medicaid: true,
  Vitals: true,
},
eligibilityVerification: {
  Mentioned: true,
}
```

}

Comment: Please fix the [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) of your question.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score -1):

To filter out only the true values in the object, you can use the Object.entries()

```
const filteredErrors = Object.entries(errors)
  .filter(([key, value]) => value)
  .reduce((obj, [key, value]) => ({ ...obj, [key]: value }), {});
```

This will return a new object with the same structure as the original errors object, but with only the true values.

Comment: `.filter(([key, value]) => value)` - `value` will always be truthy.